# Scala slick left innerjoin for same Postgres Table not working

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I am pretty new in scala. Currently working on scala 2 and postgres is the DB. Now I have written a Left innerjoin query in slick like below

```
val executors = TableQuery[Executors] 
val innerJoin = (for {
      (rel,a) <- executors joinLeft executors on ( (e1, e2) => {
    e1.column1 === e2.column1 && e1.column2 === e2.column2
    } ) if rel.id === id
  } yield rel.name)
```

When I tried to print `innerJoin.result.statements.headOption` it gives me desired query

But the problem I am facing is instead of yielding `rel.name` I want `a.name`. But I am getting error `value name is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Executors]]`.

I checked `slick` documentation , not sure what I am missing here .

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by `a.map(_.name)` . Reference https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/queries.html